# Gitlab CI runner not building or showing any output

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-omnibus

Yesterday I upgraded from Gitlab 7.x to 8.0.4 and almost everything went smoothly.  I was using the CI before without issue and after the upgrade had to migrate or start fresh.  I chose to start fresh since I only had one project.

I have added a new shell runner (tried both gitlab-ci-multi-runner and gitlab-runner) multiple times and registration is successful and the runner shows it's active in the web console. But when I try to build my code the only output in the browser is the black "console" with the spinner running forever.

If I check the files in my shell I can see the code was successfully checked out but I can't tell if any of the build script was executed or not.

I'm not sure what logs I can check as everything I've found doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Is the build status 'pending' or 'running'?

If you reload the build page is there output?

Is the runner either shared or assigned to the project?

Comment: It's 'running'.  Page reload shows nothing new.  I've tried both shared and assigned runners with the same result

Comment: So it seems after switching to gitlab-runner it actually builds, but I can't see any progress in the webview.

Comment: I've upgraded to the latest 8.1 and the issue hasn't been resolved.  I tried completely uninstalling gitlab-ci-multi-runner and purged all configs.  I removed the user and home directory and reinstalled.  Still the issue remains. 
The build says it's running in the admin console, I can see the files have been checked out in the /home/gitlab-runner/builds/... but there is NO output in the admin console.  I see the black box with the spinning arrows but nothing else.  I've tried in both Chrome and Safari with the same results.  This worked perfectly in the 7 series...

Answer (score 2):

I finally found an answer.  It looks like a permission problem. I believe it has to with the history.  As per https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/issues/187 I just removed the files in /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-ci/builds as I didn't care about the history.